# Is there an intent to deep link into the Check for Software Update settings screen?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-deep-link

There doesn't appear to be an intent listed on https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings for the Settings screen that checks for updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it via:

```
startActivity(new Intent("android.settings.SYSTEM_UPDATE_SETTINGS"));
```

I have tested it on Android 8, 12 and 13 and on Samsung, LG and Pixel, so it seems to be universal.